# logging archive with boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I am working on a software which uses boost::serialization to serialize a lot of things using text_i/oarchive.

I'd like to build a log archive for debugging purposes because the output of the text archive really is a pain to read.

I've tried using the simple_log_archive from the example : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/simple_log.html but as stated it lacks some features: "it will not display the data from the derived type given the pointer to a polymorphic base class", but that's exactly what I need...

there is an other example, log_archive: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/derivation.html which also seems to be a good starting point, it should work with polymorphic types and judging by this:

```
template<class T>
void save_override(T & t, BOOST_PFTO int){
    // make it a name-value pair and pass it on.
    // this permits this to be used even with data types which
    // are not wrapped with the name
    base::save_override(boost::serialization::make_nvp(NULL, t), 0);
}
```

I thought I could safely assume it would work for non nvp members

**but** it inherits from `boost::archive::xml_oarchive_impl` and so includes `<boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>`. But doing this causes a flood of errors because it is trying to register non nvp members on xml_oarchive ...

I've been googling and trying to find a solution to this for the past couple hours, so maybe some of you already did it or knows either how to fix simple_log_archive to work with polymorphic types or log_archive to avoid complaining about non nvp members.

Comment: How would you expect the archive to know the names for your serialized members?

Comment: I'm think an empty name for a start, a type maybe latter that would be better than nothing. The problem for now is just to get it to work :) Maybe in a distant future support both nvp and non nvp members so that we can selectively decide to have better logging.